# Odoo server not recognizing 'mumu' as database name on localhost:8069

Tags: odoo-16, postgres-12

**Facing problem in running odoo server localhost:8069**

After running the command `python odoo-bin -r mumu -w mumu --addons-path=addons -d mumu` the output error-

```
2023-06-03 14:26:06,127 3592 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 16.0 
2023-06-03 14:26:06,127 3592 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['F:\\odoo\\odoo-16.0\\odoo\\addons', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\openerp s.a\\odoo\\addons\\16.0', 'f:\\odoo\\odoo-16.0\\addons', 'f:\\odoo\\odoo-16.0\\odoo\\addons']
2023-06-03 14:26:06,127 3592 INFO ? odoo: database: mumu@default:default
2023-06-03 14:26:06,299 3592 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2023-06-03 14:26:06,555 3592 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on MUMU:8069 
2023-06-03 14:26:06,602 3592 ERROR ? odoo.modules.loading: Database mumu not initialized, you can force it with `-i base` 
2023-06-03 14:26:06,602 3592 INFO ? odoo.modules.registry: Registry loaded in 0.047s
2023-06-03 14:26:33,546 3592 ERROR mumu odoo.http: Exception during request handling. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
             ^^^^^^
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1596, in _serve_ir_http
    ir_http = self.registry['ir.http']
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 190, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'ir.http'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1989, in __call__
    response = request._serve_db()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1588, in _serve_db
    exc.error_response = self.registry['ir.http']._handle_error(exc)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 190, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'ir.http'
2023-06-03 14:26:33,666 3592 INFO mumu werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2023 14:26:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - 1 0.001 0.123
2023-06-03 14:27:06,649 3592 ERROR mumu odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
            SELECT latest_version
            FROM ir_module_module
             WHERE name='base'

ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 3:             FROM ir_module_module
                         ^

2023-06-03 14:27:06,649 3592 WARNING mumu odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Tried to poll an undefined table on database mumu.
2023-06-03 14:27:07,706 3592 ERROR mumu odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
            SELECT latest_version
            FROM ir_module_module
             WHERE name='base'

ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 3:             FROM ir_module_module
                         ^

2023-06-03 14:27:07,706 3592 WARNING mumu odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Tried to poll an undefined table on database mumu.
2023-06-03 14:27:42,235 3592 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating shutdown 
2023-06-03 14:27:42,235 3592 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
Exception in thread odoo.service.cron.cron0:
Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-06-03 14:27:43,314 3592 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 3 connections
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\server.py", line 497, in target
    self.cron_thread(i)
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\server.py", line 469, in cron_thread
    pg_conn.poll()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
Exception in thread odoo.service.cron.cron1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\server.py", line 497, in target
    self.cron_thread(i)
  File "F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\server.py", line 469, in cron_thread
    pg_conn.poll()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
(venv) PS F:\odoo\odoo-16.0> python odoo-bin -r mumu -w mumu --addons-path=addons -d mumu
2023-06-03 14:30:16,491 1788 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 16.0 
2023-06-03 14:30:16,491 1788 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['F:\\odoo\\odoo-16.0\\odoo\\addons', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\openerp s.a\\odoo\\addons\\16.0', 'f:\\odoo\\odoo-16.0\\addons', 'f:\\odoo\\odoo-16.0\\odoo\\addons']
2023-06-03 14:30:16,491 1788 INFO ? odoo: database: mumu@default:default
2023-06-03 14:30:16,774 1788 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2023-06-03 14:30:17,041 1788 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on MUMU:8069 
2023-06-03 14:30:17,083 1788 ERROR ? odoo.modules.loading: Database mumu not initialized, you can force it with `-i base` 
2023-06-03 14:30:17,083 1788 INFO ? odoo.modules.registry: Registry loaded in 0.058s
2023-06-03 14:31:17,128 1788 ERROR mumu odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
            SELECT latest_version
            FROM ir_module_module
             WHERE name='base'

ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 3:             FROM ir_module_module
                         ^

2023-06-03 14:31:17,128 1788 WARNING mumu odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Tried to poll an undefined table on database mumu.
2023-06-03 14:31:18,168 1788 ERROR mumu odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
            SELECT latest_version
            FROM ir_module_module
             WHERE name='base'

ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 3:             FROM ir_module_module
                         ^

2023-06-03 14:31:18,168 1788 WARNING mumu odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Tried to poll an undefined table on database mumu.
```

Mainly I am facing problem in my database creation of server name mumu and data_base name mumu is not identified by odoo .

I have also changed the odoo.conf file to -

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = mumu
db_password = mumu
addons_path = F:\odoo\odoo-16.0\addons
default_productivity_apps = True
```

I expect to seek help and fix the problem.